# Angular directive not transcluding select

Tags: angularjs

I have a select

```
<select selectwrap></select>
```

and a directive

```
app.directive('selectwrap', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div style="border:1px solid blue;height:100px;width:100px;" ng-transclude></div>',
        replace: false

    }
});
```

For some reason if I use replace: true, it replaces the select appropriately but when I turn it off in effort to wrap the select with the div, it doesn't do anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the select element inside your directive element.  Try instead, allowing your directive as an element and changing your html to this:

```
<selectwrap><select></select><selectwrap>
```

Or as an attribute like this:

```
<div selectwrap><select></select></div>
```

Comment: Well, you could do that using `transclude:'element'` instead of `transclude:true` but you will loose the `<select>` element anyway. You would need to add it to the template if you want it on the compiled result.